# Google App Engine wont show all URL Routes

Tags: php, google-app-engine, xampp, yaml, app.yaml

Im having problems trying to transfer and run my PHP app to local environment by using their server port 8080 on Google App Engine.
Im having problems with how app.yaml works. Heres my following code for y app.yaml:

```
application: huge
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1


handlers:
 - url: /.*
 script: public/index.php

 - url: /login/index
 script: application/view/login/index.php
```

the first url and scrip work. However my app is not the same as it is normally on XAMPP. The PHP app is structured as a MVC which means the PHP files arent in the root directory, rather in organised folders and i am using laravel and composer in XAMPP. I am now transferring this app to GAE. The main root file is in public/index.html but all other files are in folders as you can see i tried calling one page in the second script call like `application/view/login/index.php`. Also the css inside the `public/css` folder does not get loaded so the styling has gone from the application. Do I have to tell google app engine every single route? If so, can someone show me one example how the second call would work and how I would call my css to work also.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the handlers in the `app.yaml` file matters, the first pattern matching will be used.

In your case `/login/index` is actually matching `/.*`, so it will be passed to the 1st handler. To do what you expect it to do you need to swap the order of the handlers.

You may also need to add static files/dirs handlers for non-php files (for example for the css files)

You should spend some time making yourself familiar with configuring php apps: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig